# Questions about eigenvalues of matrices in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

I have some questions about eigenvalues of matrices in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Since $\mathbb{F}_q$ is not algebraically closed, it is possible that some $g \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has eigenvalues which are not in $\mathbb{F}_q$. It is said that in this case, the eigenvalues of $g$ must be in $\mathbb{F}_q(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$, $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{F}_q \backslash \mathbb{F}_q^2$. Why this is true? Thank you very much.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is quadratic, so its zeros belong to a quadratic extension. However, if $q$ is a power of two, the said quadratic extension is NOT of the form $\Bbb{F}_q(\sqrt\varepsilon)$, because in that case all the elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ have a square root in $\Bbb{F}_2$. IOW, the claim is false in characteristic two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a good point, actually. I'll edit to that effect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You know that the eigenvalues satisfy the characteristic polynomial which is degree $2$. Apply the quadratic formula.

EDIT: As Jyrki points out, we have a bit of a sticking point in characteristic $2$ sinc the quadratic formula doesn't work there. But, we're still in a quadratic extension. In other words, the classic field theory problem "all quadratic extensions are obtained by adjoining a squareroot" usually follows with "except in characteristic $2$" :)

Comment: thank you very much. Let $g=(a,b;c,d)$. Then eigenvalues are $\lambda=\frac{a+d\pm \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}}{2}$. Therefore $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q(\sqrt{\epsilon}), \epsilon \in \mathbb{F}_q$. But why $\epsilon \in \mathbb{F}_q\backslash \mathbb{F}_q^2$?

Comment: @LJR Have you seen my edit? If you can use quadratic formula, then you can force the squarefree part by just factoring any existing squarefree part out and ignoring it. For example, $\mathbb{F}_7(\sqrt{8})=\mathbb{F}_7(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: yes, I understand this. But we have $\epsilon \in \mathbb{F}_q$. We don't need to write $\epsilon \in \mathbb{F}_q^2$. Is this true? The claim in the post is in the middle of page 69 the book [representation theory](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf).

Comment: now I understand. I confused with the notation before.